# Lightroom text/attributes not showing in Windows Explorer

Tags: metadata, windows, lightroom-6

I'm trying to switch from Picasa to Lightroom on the recommendation of a number of people.  However, one major thing I haven't been able to figure out - in Lightroom (v6), whenever I add info like tags, those aren't showing in Windows Explorer (Win 7) when I view the files.  All the tags from Picasa show in Explorer, and Lightroom also recognizes them as keywords.  Is there a way to get these (and the star ratings) to show in Explorer when they're added through Lightroom?

Answer (score 2):

Lightroom doesn't per default write to the image files, it only stores the info in it's database. If you want to have that info available externally, you can say "write metadata" in the context menu, or activate an option in the preferences "write changes automatically to XMP" (or similar). "XMP" in this case stands for the XMP space in JPEGs or XMP sidecar files for non-writeable formats (raw files). (be aware that this can generate quite some harddisk activity when you make changes to 1000 photos at once...)